# Is there an equivalent of MATLB rinexread for Python?

Tags: python, matlab

I need to read some RINEX 3 observational files. In the past I used the MATLAB function rinexread. Now I need to use python.

I tried georinex.load but is way slower than the MATLAB function. Is there something else I could try?